# Why does my app appear to be using a Windows 95 GUI?

Tags: windows, user-interface

I have a program that I am working on. And for some reason, every component when run looks like it's from Windows 95. Is there a way to update this to something more modern? All my other programs use a current looking GUI.

**Edit:** Here is the solution for a C# application:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.DoEvents();
```

Comment: Which programming language and framework are you using?

Comment: Maybe you should show us some of the code.

Comment: Please don't add "[SOLVED]" to titles, just accept a correct answer or post the solution as an answer and then click the green tick.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwtazz9d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that allows the use of comctl32.dll in version 6 and newer. This is usually done automatically when you create a GUI project in Visual Studio. In other IDEs, there are often similar menu options (e.g. [Code::Blocks "WinXP Look'n'Feel" plugin](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code%3a%3aBlocks_Plugins)) so that you don't have to write such a file yourself (which isn't very hard, mostly copy-paste from the link above).

The file must be named "something.exe.manifest".

Comment: Thank you. I actually found out that this code works.                      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.DoEvents();

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you need to add an [application manifest to enable Windows XP+ visual styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I found out that this code works as well Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.DoEvents();